# Add file prefix in Photoshop droplet

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I'm trying to setup a Photoshop droplet that will:

1. Resize to fit 2500x2500px
2. Save for Web (or Save as JPG) in a specific folder
3. Resize to fit 600x600px
4. Save for Web (or Save as JPG) in the same folder, but with prefix of "T_"
5. Close image

Is that possible? I can't seem to find a way to add the prefix at stage 4.

Thanks, Frank

Comment: You want to use automation?

Comment: I'm actually not sure what that means! Is automation part of Photoshop? Or an OS thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a bit more experimenting, I've found a way that works!

Record the following as an action:

1. Fit image to 2500x2500px
2. Save for Web as JPG in destination folder
3. Fit image to 600x600px
4. Save As some new name (can be anything) in destination folder
5. Close image

Then, create a droplet, choosing Destination as the same folder as above. Check the Override Action "Save As" Commands option, and under File Naming, enter the prefix, then document name, then extension.

Doing it this way, the droplet's *Override Action "Save As" Commands* bit overrides the filename created in step 4, but leaves step 2 as it is – so you end up with one larger image with the original filename, and a smaller one with a prefix.

Hope that makes sense to anyone else who hits this problem!

Comment: Hi Frank! You can mark your own answer as "accepted"! I use this technique as well and it's very easy to customize.

Comment: I find that it will always save the file as whatever file name was used when the Save For Web action was recorded. This is not only annoying, it means bulk processing is impossible with Save For Web because each subsequent file overwrites the previous one. Save As can be recorded without this problem, but it leaves the file as a .PSD, which is equally useless. Or am I misunderstanding your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I’m a few versions behind in my Photoshop and I do this kind of stuff with AppleScript, but try this:

1. Resize to fit 2500x2500px
2. Save for Web (or Save as JPG) in a specific folder
3. Resize to fit 600x600px
4. Rename the current document with a prefix of “T_”
5. Save for Web (or Save as JPG) in the same folder
6. Close image (without saving)

If that doesn’t work and there is no way to do what you want with Actions, then you might want to script it because what you have here is a classic template for export scripts: open a document, do some kind of modification, export a copy to this folder with this particular name, close the document without saving, repeat. You just have to essentially translate it into AppleScript or JavaScript.

There is documentation from Adobe:

[Adobe Photoshop Scripting](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/scripting.html)

With AppleScript at least, you can also create droplets, but you can involve other apps so that your exported files get pushed to a Web server or whatever else you might want to include in that workflow.

Comment: Yes maybe Scripting is the way to go. I can't do applescript as this is to run on my client's PC, but I can probably do it with JS. Do you know whether a JS Photoshop script can be turned into a droplet? I need to make it as easy as possible for my client to batch process thousands of images... Thanks!